# How to setup php in my Angular project?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am trying to setup a angular project that has PHP backend. My project is setup as followed:

```
project
   -app
     -api
       -test.php
     -scripts
       -app.js
       -test.controller.js
     -css
     -images
     ...others
```

In my test.controller.js

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($http) {

 $http.get('api/test.php').then(function(res) {
     console.log(res)
 })
 ...more
});
```

Inside my test.php

```
<?php
    ..php codes
    ..calculate stuff.
    ..generate $result

echo json_encode($result);
```

For some reason, when I load the page, all I can see from the request is just my entire test.php code instead of the data I need.

For example:
The return I've got

```
"<?php↵header("Content-Type: application/json", true);...more...
```

I do have my virtual host setup and I am not sure what went wrong. Could someone help me about it?

Comment: Sounds like your webserver (Apache or Nginx probably) is misconfigured, isn't handling PHP files correctly. You are using a webserver here, and not just loading these files from local paths right?

Comment: I have a virtual host setup in my machine and I also point the document root to my app. Isn't that enough for what I need? +1

Comment: In theory, yes. But only if Apache is properly configured to handle PHP. Forget angular for a bit, just load `api/test.php` in a browser, and troubleshoot the PHP issue.

Comment: If you are using php 5 and above type this in the root of your project `php -S localhost:4001` then navigate to http://localhost:4001 that way you wuld be sure that you php serve is being ran